# Updating row in database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update and save a row of a database table. I have used a version of this code to just populate a  GridView and it works, so I am assuming it has something to do with my SQL statment; I do not get an error, the table just does not update. On the page load event I have the textboxes being populated by the information of the row, and I have a global variable, named 'temp', that will save the title of the row so I can use it in the button's click event. The error I am getting states that I have not given a value for one of my required parameters. My Locals tab on the debugger shows that every variable has a value, though the one I try to update is not the new data but still the old data.
I have looked at several examples and I cannot find the problem though. Thank you for any assistance.

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strTitle As String = txtTitle.Text
    Dim strConsole As String = txtConsole.Text
    Dim strYear As String= txtYear.Text
    Dim strPurchase As String = calDate.SelectedDate.ToString

    Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "DATA SOURCE=" + Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data", "db1.accdb"))
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()

        cmd.CommandText = Convert.ToString("UPDATE Video_Games SET Title = @title, Console = @Console, Year_Released = @Year_Released, Purchase = @Purchase WHERE Title=" & temp)
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", strTitle)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Console", strConsole)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year_Released", strYear)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purchase", strPurchase)

        con.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Using

    Server.Transfer("Form.aspx", True)
End Sub
```

I have also tried the have my where statement as: `WHERE Title='" & temp & "'")` Though this does not work either.

[This is the details of the Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38HHX.png)

Comment: `Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` if the result is non zero, the DB is being updated.  Dates saved as string?  Bad idea.

Comment: Title is used both as where condition and as set value. There is no record to update if you pass a new title.

Comment: On my page load event I populate the textboxes with the row's information. I added a global variable that will store the title of the row so I can use it on my button's SQL statement. This works and save the Title to the temp variable. The end of the SQL statement is now `"WHERE Title=" & temp`. This, however, gives me an error stating that I have not given a value for one of my required parameters. My Locals tab on the debugger shows that every variable has a value, except the one I try to update is not the new data but still the old data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the relevant part of your changes

Comment: I don't know how picky Oledb provider is but your `@Title` param has a capital "T" but your query does not.

Comment: Or maybe you need to use `?` instead of parameter name in the sql string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.parametername(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: @Crowcoder cannot be that. OleDb doesn't even look at the name of the parameters. The only thing that matters is the order of them. The error message is unclear but if it complains about a missing parameter then perhaps one or more field names or the table name is mispelled

Comment: A well asked question will post the entire error message, there are usually more clues in there than you think.

Comment: I added a screen snippet of the error. I also copied all my names from the database and pasted them in my code to make sure, still getting the error.

Comment: chances are one of your 4 parameters is null or a blank string, hence the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your assistance, This is such a wonderful community.

The problem, I found out, does not even have to do with the button's click event, it had to do with the page load event. Since on page load the row's information is loaded and populated into the textboxes, when the button is clicked to update the fields, the page load event triggers again and reloads the old information into fields, essentially saving the old information instead of the new. My fix was to create an `If Not IsPostBack Then` statement that encapsulates my on page load code. Therefore the code does not get saved when the button is pressed. Another this, I did not need the temp variable, using `WHERE Title='" + strTitle + "'"` worked. Hopefully this helps other people stuck on a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

I changed you commandText as seen below and created a blank database with a table named just like yours and the update worked

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Video_Games SET Title = @title, Console = @Console, Year_Released = @Year_Released, Purchase = @Purchase WHERE Title='" & temp & "'"
```

I set my variable for Title = Super Mario Bros and then the temp variable to Wario World.  I had a record in my database with the title of Wario World, and running the update changed the title to Super Mario Bros.

Check if you temp variable is different from your @title variable.  Also check that you have the record int the table for your temp variable title

Answer (score -2):

Using dates in a where clause is always ify as they are floating point numbers and may not match equally. I'd try and round them or convert them to strings before comparison, e.g. something along these lines:

```
UPDATE Video_Games SET Title = @title, Console = @Console, Year_Released = @Year_Released, Format(Purchase, ""m/d/yyyy"") = Format(@Purchase, ""m/d/yyyy"") WHERE Title = @Title
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting an error on the update command. I just changed the variable to a string `Dim strPurchase As String = calDate.SelectedDate.ToString` to make it easier. Thank you for you input. Though the database still is not updating.